# JS function with two arguments, referencing different objects

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty much brand new to JS, and working on a small web page to teach myself a little bit. I feel like this would have been answered before, but I don't know how to word it better to find it.. sorry!

basically, I have two templates set up in HTML, for two select boxes, which will be re-used quite a few times across the form. then I have a function that is called Onchange for select 1, and will change what is visible in select 2, I managed to reference select 1 with (this), but I'm completely at a loss as to how to reference the second one.

```js
function myFunction(selectObject) 
{
    if (selectObject.value == 'option1') 
    {
      //code to reference Select2 here
      option3.disabled = true;
      option3.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<template id="Select1">
    <select name="Select1" onchange="myFunction(this)">
      <option value="option">option</option>
      <option value="option1">option1</option>
      <option value="option2">option2</option>
    </select>
</template>

<template id="Select2">
    <select name="Select2" >
      <option value="option3">option</option>
      <option value="option4">option1</option>
      <option value="option5">option2</option>
    </select>
</template>
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to get familiar with [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Events), [dom query API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and possibly [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

If you're using templates, you need to search inside [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) property of the corresponding template:

```
let t1 = document.querySelector('#Select1');
let t2 = document.querySelector('#Select2');

// there are many ways how to select an element, here simple element selector is used
let select1 = t1.content.querySelector('select');
let select2 = t2.content.querySelector('select');
let option3 = t1.content.querySelector('[value=option3]');

 // add event listener is preferred to your `onchange` attribute binding
 select1.addEventListener('change', function() {
       // modify select2 here
       option3.disabled = true;
       option3.style.display = "none";
 });
```

Comment: so I forgot to mention it in the original post, but I will be re-using the templates quite a few times, sorry about that. Will selecting them by name still work in that case?

Comment: @saintshenanigans, updated my answer. But although you can access the DOM elements, they are not rendered inside the template, so you need to paste them somewhere else before you can listen to `change` event.

Comment: @saintshenanigans, please, consider accepting my answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I am not sure why are you using template tags.

```js
function myFunction() 
{
    var select1 = document.querySelector("#Select1>select");
    var select2 = document.querySelector("#Select2>select");
    
    var option3Visible = select1.value != 'option1'; 
    
    var option3 = select2.querySelector("option[value='option3']");
    option3.disabled = !option3Visible;
    option3.style.display = option3Visible ? "inline" : "none";    
}
```

```html
<div id="Select1">
    <select name="Select1" onchange="myFunction()">
      <option value="option0">option0</option>
      <option value="option1">option1</option>
      <option value="option2">option2</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="Select2">
    <select name="Select2" >
      <option value="option3">option3</option>
      <option value="option4">option4</option>
      <option value="option5">option5</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, I should have specified. I'm working on a from that uses a bunch of select boxes, most of them will be identical and just change what's visible in the others depending on what's selected, so I used templates to make the code easier to navigate/change